# spark-submit job FAILS in Azure HDInsight in --deploy-mode cluster when --py-files are provided

Tags: azure, pyspark, azure-hdinsight, spark-submit

Facing Same issue as in [Spark submit failing in yarn cluster mode when specifying --files in an Azure HDIinsight cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59973141/spark-submit-failing-in-yarn-cluster-mode-when-specifying-files-in-an-azure-hd)

But could not see any answers on above post.

Issue:
Spark-submit job fails when: `--master yarn --deploy-mode cluster` and when `--py-files ZIPfile.zip` is provided
It works fine in `--master yarn --deploy-mode client` mode.

Is there something wrong with Azure HDInsight 4.0 ?

Comment: To know exact reason, I would request you to share the complete stack trace of the error message which you are experiencing? 

By sharing the stack trace helps us to provide the solution accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I referred to the link. It could be related to the permission issue which is not able to create the directory. The directory referred `/mnt/resource/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/<username>/appcache/<applicationID>` is used to store the intermediate results and then it goes to HDFS/memory depending whether it is written to a path or stored in temp tables respectively. The user might not have permission. Once the job finishes it gets flushed out. Providing correct permissions to the user in the path `/mnt/resource/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache` in the specific worker node should resolve the issue.

You mentioned it's getting executed successfully in spark-shell or deploy mode as a client. So let me explain to you what's the difference

**Spark Client**

1. The driver component of the spark job is basically running in the machine where you are submitting the job and appropriate jars/files are present in that machine. This means it has all available resources at its disposal to execute work.

**Spark cluster**

1. The driver runs on one of the cluster's Worker nodes. The worker is chosen by the Master.

So, coming on to your issue, are files/jars distributed across the nodes or placed in a Azure Storage(where the WNs can access it)? If not please place the files in the identical directory (as in head nodes) in all worker nodes and then execute. You can make use of the `script action` of the HDInsight cluster to place the files in the nodes. In case if it still fails please paste the full error trace.